# Load a products.json file with fetch in react typescript

Tags: react-hooks, react-typescript

```
import Button from "@material-ui/icons/Button";
import data from "../data/products.json";

// Styles
import { Wrapper } from "./Item.styles";

// Types
type Props = {
    item: data;
}

const Item: React.FC<Props> = () => {

}

export default Item;
```

I'm new to typescript, and I don't know how to load a json file with fetch and map the items correctly.